# Intersection Observer Not Working Wordpress 5.8.1

Tags: javascript, wordpress, lazy-loading

I implemented Intersection Observer on my Wordpress site which is on dev mode atm and just the last image at the bottom of the site is lazyloading.

Not sure the reason why that is happening. See below my lazy code.

```
 /*Lazy load images*/
 const allViews = document.querySelectorAll("[data-src]");

 function preloadImage(img) {
   const src = img.getAttribute("data-src");
     if (!src) {
      return;
 }
  img.src = src;
 }
 const options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: "0px",
 };

const callback = function (entries) {
//console.log(entries);
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
     if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
       return;
  } else {
  console.log(entry.target);
  preloadImage(entry.target);
  observer.unobserve(entry.target);
     }
   });
 }, options);

 allViews.forEach((image) => {
 observer.observe(image);
 });
```

On another file, I have a jquery script adding the data-src attribute to all images and adding the lazyload class:

```
  /*change img src to img data-src for lazy load*/
  $("img").each(function () {
    $(this).attr("data-src", $(this).attr("src"));
    $(this).addClass('lazyload');
    //$(this).removeAttr("src");
    //console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML);
});
```

Any help will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still confused why are you actually using this method because wordpress already has native loading="lazy" support

1. Javascript might execute in the order it loaded, If the Jquery code
   is not loaded before the IntersectionObserver code, Your script
   become useless.
2. you have comment out //$(this).removeAttr("src"); which means, src attribute still exist and the image will be loaded normally. You should uncomment it.
3. Instead of spending time developing a lazyload you could simply leave to wordpress do it natively lazy load, or use Plugins like W3 Total Cache, which has inbuilt support for Lazy Loading.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. The lazy load from Wordpress 5.8.1 is not working and not sure if that is because my images are all webp. By any means, in another website the IO codes are working fine and not errors at all. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: Native lazy loading has a threshold of 2500px, It will load any images that comes with in the 2500px, So if your total website height falls with in it, naive Lazy loading wil not work as all images will be loaded instantly
Source: https://web.dev/browser-level-image-lazy-loading/

Comment: Thanks for that @Niresh. My native Wordpress lazyload is disabled and I managed to make it work, but all the images are loading immediately hehe. At least Google is not complaining...Google s**ks

Comment: I'm glad that you made it work :)